# DSSIM loss function in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I defined a DSSIM loss function in keras. here is my function:

```
 import keras.backend as K

 def DSSIM_coef(y_true,y_pred, c1, c2):




     u_true=K.mean(y_true, axis=-1)
     u_pred=K.mean(y_pred, axis=-1)

     var_true=K.var(y_true, axis=-1)
     var_pred=K.var(y_pred, axis=-1)


     std_true=K.sqrt(var_true)
     std_pred=K.sqrt(var_pred)


     ssim=(2*u_true*u_pred+c1)*(2*std_pred*std_true+c2)
     denom=(u_true**2+u_pred**2+c1)*(var_pred+var_true+c2)

     ssim/=K.clip(denom, K.epsilon(),np.inf)

     return K.mean((1.0-ssim)/2.0)


 def DSSIM_Loss(c1,c2):
    def DSSIM(y_true,y_pred):
      return DSSIM_coef(y_true,y_pred, c1, c2)
    return DSSIM
```

I used this loss function to penalize the dissimilarity between ground truth output of a CNN and predicted output. I also used RMSPROP as my optimizer with lr=0.001. After compiling the model and training it, I saw that loss value remained constant(0.321) for all epochs. I will be appreciated if you give me some points?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `(2*std_pred*std_true+c2)`
`2*std_pred*std_true` this is not the covariance of x and y;

I think you can either use two methods instead:

1. `SSIMLoss = 1 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true,y_pred))`
   this would give you loss in range [0, 2]
2. `DSSIM = tf.reduce_mean((1 - tf.image.ssim(y_true,y_pred)) / 2)`
   this would give you loss in range [0, 1]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity